# How to redirect user to login page when refreshing the page in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my application I want to redirect the user to the login page when he refreshes the page he is viewing. How can I do this in AngularJS?

Comment: Do you hold a session while he is logged in?

Comment: @Guy yes, I am holding

Comment: What happens when the session is `null`?

Answer (score 0):

You may listen to event [$locationChangeStarted](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location#events_%24locationchangestart) and, if user not logged in, prevent default behavior (`preventDefault()` method of event object) and change [$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location#methods_path) to any page you want.

Here is a pseudocoded example:

```
myModule.run(function($locaiton, $rootScope, MyLoginService) {
   $rootScope.on('$locationChangeStarted', function(event) {
       if (!MyLoginService.isAuthentificated() && event.oldUrl !== 'myloginpage') {
          event.preventDefault();
          $location.path('/myloginpage');
       }
   });
});
```