# AngularJS cache issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, laravel

We have a project that combines angularJS and laravel based on https://github.com/davemo/end-to-end-with-angularjs. However, we have an issue when it comes to caching.

We have a template that displays the URL parameters, which are passed in by the controller `$scope.param1 = $routeParams.userId;`

When you go to a page `http://localhost/#/foo/bar`, the template displays

```
<h1>foo</h1>
<h2>bar</h2>
```

But when you click through to, or change the URL to `http://localhost/#/thunk/foo`, you still get the template showing

```
<h1>foo</h1>
<h2>bar</h2>
```

Until you do a shift reload of the page. Then you get:

```
<h1>thunk</h1>
<h2>foo</h2>
```

Any idea on what is causing the issue and if angularJS has a ignore cache function?

Example code

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngSanitize']);

/********************************/
/*
 * Routes
 */

app.config(function($routeProvider) {

  // User profile
  $routeProvider.when('/:userId' , {
    templateUrl : 'templates/profile/profileLanding.html' ,
    controller : 'ProfileLandingController' ,
    resolve : {
      profileDetails : function(UserProfileService) {
        return UserProfileService.getDetails();
      }
    }
  });

});

/********************************/
/*
 * Models
 */

app.run(function($rootScope, $location, AuthenticationService, FlashService) {

// User pofile
app.factory("UserProfileService" , function($http , $route) {

  // Get id from param
  var id = $route.current.params.userId;

  return {

    // Get user details
    getDetails : function() {
      return $http({
        url: '/user', 
        method: "GET",
        params: {user_id: id}
      });
    }

  }
});

/********************************/
/*
 * Controllers
 */

app.controller("ProfileLandingController" , function($scope , $routeParams , profileDetails) {
  $scope.param1 = $routeParams.userId;
  $scope.details = profileDetails.data;
});
```

Comment: How do you monitor your location changes? Maybe you should try $locationChangeStarted event? In [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134667/how-to-redirect-user-to-login-page-when-refreshing-the-page-in-angular-js/21135143#21135143) post there is an example of how to bind to this event

Comment: I think the issue might be coming from the factory.

Comment: I do not think, that this is a right approach. I thing you should pass  ```id``` parameter to your getDetails function from some controller. Also, you will be able to extract ```id``` from your route easily in controller using ```$routeParams``` service

Comment: Thank you Andrey Shustariov :)